# Why is th:attr in button not sending the correct data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

```
    <th:block th:each="fh : ${datacenterFisicHosts}">
        <div>
            <tr class="row">
                <td id="fisicHostName" th:text="${fh.name}"></td>
                <td id="fisicHostIp" th:text="${fh.ip}"></td>
                <td id="fisicHostOS" th:text="${fh.operatingSystem}"></td>
                <td id="fisicHostNotes" th:text="${fh.notes}"></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="credentialsButton btn btn-default btn-sm" th:attr="data-fisic-host-id=${fh.id}">CREDENCIALES</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-deleteFH" th:attr="data-fhId=${fh.id}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> Eliminar
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </th:block>
</table>
```

This is strange because this is working:

```
<button class="credentialsButton btn btn-default btn-sm" th:attr="data-fisic-host-id=${fh.id}">CREDENCIALES</button>
```

and this is not:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-deleteFH" th:attr="data-fhId=${fh.id}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> Eliminar
                    </button>
```

This is the JS code for the not working issue:

```
 $('.btn-deleteFH').click(function() {
    var fisicHostId = $(this).data('fhId');
    console.log(fisicHostId);
});
```

When I click in the button I get an 'undefined' in the console.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: jQuery questions should be presented with rendered markup, not server-side templating.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `data()` only works on attributes that start with `data-`

Change it to

```
th:attr="data-fhId=${fh.id}"
```

Also you can't use `this` in an arrow function since arrow functions have no explicit `this`

Change

```
$('.btn-deleteFH').click( () => {
```

To

```
$('.btn-deleteFH').click(function() {
```

Comment: It is still undefined ... isn't it weird ?

Comment: What does rendered html look like? Did you change the arrow function?

Comment: I did changed everything you told me ... I'll edit the code in the question so you can have a better look !

Comment: Updated ... Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Well ... I fixed it by naming the variable in the same way as the other one ... but I can't still find what the problem was ... this is crazy !